# eosio-explorer can't see block and transactions,postgreSQL light is red

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.system

I want to build a local blcokchain explorer. I used the offical eosio-explorer, but it didn't work. The postgreSQL light always red. I can't search the block form number or transactions. I can use the pgadmin connect the pgDB in docker. Who konws how to fix that? Thanks.

- My environment： eosio 2.0.2 - start the state-history-pulgin and
  connecting to external nodeos endpoint

Comment: Have enabled all the ports?

Comment: Yes,because i can connect the DB by use pgadmin4.

Comment: I have the same issue. Gary, have you find the solution? Thanks